# Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Tags: devops

while i installing apache in amazon linux ec2 instance it showing error  like Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.31-1.8.amzn1.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

remove the old version before installing a new version

Answer (score 0):

Both versions can be installed on the same system. You can even switch back and forth between them.

You'll just have to disable httpd, enable httpd24, and symlink the original binary to the new version. On RH7 httpd24 gets installed in /opt/rh/httpd24. YMMV.